# Click elements and set as 'Active' using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple script that shows 6 boxes.

The plan is when the user clicks any of these boxes, they should turn to grey background. However, this doesn't work. Is there something wrong with how I'm using `.on`?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/szzqe8L1/

```js
$(".thumb-overlay-content").on('click',function() {
    $(this).removeClass('rotateOut').addClass('rotateIn');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('rotateIn').addClass('rotateOut');
});
```

```css
.thumb-overlay-content { margin:10px; background:#CCC; float:left; text-align:center; padding:50px; }
.animated { background:red; }
.rotateOut { border:3px solid blue; }
.rotateIn { border:3px solid green; background:#ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">Box1</div>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">Box1</div>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">Box1</div>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">Box1</div>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">Box1</div>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">Box1</div>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">Box1</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.on('click'` expects one callback function which says what to do when the user clicks on element matching the selector.

You can get the functionality you want using `.toggleClass()`

```js
$(".thumb-overlay-content").on('click',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('rotateOut rotateIn');
});
```

```css
.thumb-overlay-content { margin:10px; background:#CCC; float:left; text-align:center; padding:50px; }
.animated { background:red; }
.rotateOut { border:3px solid blue; }
.rotateIn { border:3px solid green; background:#ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">Box1</div>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">Box1</div>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">Box1</div>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">Box1</div>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">Box1</div>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">Box1</div>
<div class="thumb-overlay-content animated rotateOut">Box1</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks @void - this worked beautifully. I had been using `click` for years so took a little time to figure this one out. Thank you.

Comment: Will do :-) You were so fast - I can accept in 2 minutes. Thank you.